# Exoplayer throws Decoder initialisation exception for large mp4 files in android

Tags: android, decoder, exoplayer

Iam using Exoplayer to play videos as a playlist continuously in android . When I play low quality mp4 videos it works fine but when i try to play higher quality mp4  videos after playing one or two videos in the playlist the screen doesnot display anything and the log gives the following exception

com.google.android.exoplayer.MediaCodecTrackRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.amlogic.avc.decoder.awesome, MediaFormat(video/avc, 198826, 1920, 1080, -1.0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)

Even if i loop the same high quality video the first time it plays and then second time this exception is thrown . when the video size is more than 80mb this exception is thrown .is it some buffer size issue ? can someone please guide me . thankyou very much

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.adplayertexture);   
    AdplayerTexture=(TextureView)findViewById(R.id.AdPlayerTexture);
    AdplayerTexture.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        AdplayerTexture.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
  }
@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width,
    int height) {

 AdPlayerSurface = new Surface( surface); 
 playMedia(AdPlayerSurface);
}


private void playMedia(Surface surface){
mediaplayer=new ExoPlayer();
mediaplayer.play(this,Videopathlist[CurrentVideoIndex],surface;
 mediaplayer.addListener(this);   
   }

@Override
public void onStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {

if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED) {
//releasing the resources   
    mediaplayer.DestroyPlayer();
AdPlayerSurface.release();

AdPlayerSurface=new Surface(AdplayerTexture.getSurfaceTexture());
    CurrentVideoIndex++;
playMedia(AdPlayerSurface);
}
```

this is the function play() in root2mediaplayer class

```
public void playMedia(Activity playerActivity,String mediapath,final long Position,Surface mediasurface){
    String Systemroot = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath();
try{
    File myFile=new File(Systemroot + java.io.File.separator + "Videos"
            + java.io.File.separator
            + mediapath);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(myFile);
    final int numRenderers = 2;

    SampleSource sampleSource = 
            new FrameworkSampleSource(playerActivity, uri, /* headers */ null, numRenderers);

    // Build the track renderers
    TrackRenderer    videoRenderer = new MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer(sampleSource, MediaCodec.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT);

    TrackRenderer    audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(sampleSource);

    // Build the ExoPlayer and start playback
    MoviePlayer = ExoPlayer.Factory.newInstance(numRenderers);
    MoviePlayer.prepare(videoRenderer, audioRenderer);

    MoviePlayer.addListener(this);
    // Pass the surface to the video renderer.
    MoviePlayer.sendMessage(videoRenderer, MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer.MSG_SET_SURFACE, mediasurface);

            MoviePlayer.seekTo(Position);
            MoviePlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
}catch(Exception e){

e.printStackTrace();
FileLog("exception in mediaplayer");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Without looking at your full code and without knowing which device/platform you see this issue (though from your question it looks like a h/w platform from AMLOGIC), I can only guess that may be you are not releasing the MediaCodec resources in your player when the playback ends and/or you switch playing new video.

MediaCodec is released in releaseCodec() API in https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/MediaCodecTrackRenderer.java.

You may want to check if that is indeed called when you stop playback of first video and start playback of next video in your playlist.

Typically, all high end mobile platforms have h/w based decoders that use limited and dedicated video memory(accessible only by h/w decoders) on the system to decode frames. In some platforms, you will not be able to create a decoder if some other app (or same app) in the system has created another instance of the same h/w based decoder, and not released it when it goes to background (in Activity Life cycle language, onStop etc) .

Additionally, if the dedicated video memory is not released when the decoders are destroyed, you will exhaust the limited video memory available on the platform in couple of video playback sessions due to the leak.

Look out for full platform adb logs when you create and destroy the MediaCodec instances (or in your case, stop and start playback of next video in playlist). That may give you some clues.

Hope my high level advice is of some use to you to hunt down the problem. Good luck!!!.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of totally tearing down ExoPlayer and the Surface you should be able to reuse the same ExoPlayer and Surface instances.

Just stop ExoPlayer, create the new FrameworkSampleSource/MediaCodec{Audio,Video}TrackRender objects, and then call `prepare` again.

The new code would do something like:

- MoviePlayer.stop()
- MoviePlayer.seekTo(0)
- new FrameworkSampleSource and MediaCodec{Audio,Video}TrackRenders
- MoviePlayer.prepare(newVideoRenderer, newAudioRenderer)

Refer to the comments for the [stop method](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/ExoPlayer.java#L319):

> /**
>      * Stops playback. Use {@code setPlayWhenReady(false)} rather than this method if the intention
>      * is to pause playback.
>      *
>
> * Calling this method will cause the playback state to transition to
>      * {@link ExoPlayer#STATE_IDLE}. The player instance can still be used, and
>      * {@link ExoPlayer#release()} must still be called on the player if it's no longer required.
>      *
>
> * Calling this method does not reset the playback position. If this player instance will be used
>      * to play another video from its start, then {@code seekTo(0)} should be called after stopping
>      * the player and before preparing it for the next video.
>      */